# How to secure Cloud Firestore collection and sub collection without any auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How do I can secure **Cloud Firestore** without any auth uid.

***Why without*** ?

Because I have a simple chat application and I am not storing their auth uid while they register.
Also they **can** open their app after **first registration** without any login so I dont know how can I understand who is logged in already and then let them to read or write operations.

Therefor I want to secure Cloud Firestore without any authentications.

Any help if is it possible ??

Comment: "*I want to secure Cloud Firestore without any authentications*" - what does that mean? If you don't require authentication in your security rules, then anyone can access the database.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to ask the question, "How can firebase detect that your user is after login part of the app?"

I would recommend not to throw auth away, but when you want to get rid of any email and password auth, you can use [anonymous login](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) or [custom auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) system that Firebase is providing.

Firestore security rules have just simple things provided that will not help solve your problem. You have request object that is providing auth, time, type, etc. and resource object that is providing firestore document data. None of those will help you.

Comment: I authenticated users with phone number, so it is a big job for a chat application every time receive code then loggin.

I am sure you used whatsapp, imo and there is a fast login without asking an credential

Comment: You can use firebase mobile number auth for that https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: i did this, but I never login any time users open the app, because it will be boring for users to wait until authenticated then the app gets open. users need supers fast launching .

Comment: When user once authenticated it gets stored and getting status of auth status on launch is super fast. Without that, I don't see a way how firebase is able to detect a specific user

Comment: Can you show me in code, I use `signInWithPhoneNumber` function every time it send a code then I can login so how Can I login without receive code??